# Why would some buttons in CK Editor not work?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ckeditor, button

I am usuing CKEditor (version 3.0.2) in a site that I built. I have used it before in other sites and never had any issues. In the current site any of the buttons that would have opened a JavaScript Popup will not work. Thinks like Bold, Source, Save all work fine. But thinks like Add Image, Link, Anchor, Table, Smiley, Special Characters, Paste From Word, and About CKEditor dont work. Any ideas as to why?

**EDIT:** This is happening on multiple computers and browsers. I have tried it on 4 computers ( 2- XP, 2- Win 7) and I have tried it on Chrome, Firefox, and several version of IE.

**EDIT: Error Console:** When the page loads the Error Console gives a Warning: Unknown Property 'mso-spacerun' and the same thing shows for 'border-radius' and 'text-overflow'. I also get a "Error in parsing value for 'filter'" in the editor.css. Those are all Warnings. There are no actual errors.

Comment: You could start checking what the error console says. If there's nothing telling there, a live link would be good.

Comment: Re your edit: Those are harmless. Can you filter for actual errors (not the warnings) in the console window?

Comment: All I get is warnings. There are no actual errors.

Comment: That's odd. Can you post a link?

Comment: Correction: There is an error... it is giving a 'invalid array length' from lightbox... so i guess the lightbox photo viewer is causing the isses with CKEditor

Comment: On first glance seems to be a conflict with Prototype (there is an error when you click on one of the buttons). What are you using prototype for?

Comment: Ahh the lightbox. Do you need it on that page?

Comment: And the prototype.js is damn old. Can you try using a current one (1.6.1, I think)? I'm not 100% sure, but I think I have prototype and CKEditor running together merrily on one page.

Comment: No i dont... I just put in a check (on the live version- you were looking at the test) and if it is the edit_page then I got rid of the lightbox includes... It is working fine now. Thanks!!!! (add an Answer and I will give you credit)

Comment: All right, answer added :) By the way, I definitely have prototype 1.6.1 and CKEditor 3.0 running alongside, so if you ever need that lightbox together with the editor, upgrading should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was a conflict with prototype. See the comments for the rest :)